# Chef Recipe, sssd configuration

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, redhat

I am trying to get a recipe to work in Chef.  However, it is failing...

I can use "default" in an attribute, but I can't use it in a recipe, and for some reason, it's squawking...  Looking to see if someone might know what I'm doing wrong here... any help would be awesome, thank you!

I edited the names of the cookbooks/recipe's/groups to keep my code anonymous.

```
default['sssd']['simple']['allow_groups'] = 'GroupName' if node.chef_environment == 'production'
default['sssd']['simple']['allow_groups'] = 'GroupName' unless node.chef_environment == 'test'
```

### NameError

```
undefined local variable or method `default' for cookbook: COOKBOOK_NAME, recipe: RECIPE:NAME :Chef::Recipe
```

### Cookbook Trace:

```
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/COOKBOOK_NAME/recipes/RECIPE_NAME.rb:4:in `from_file'
```

### Relevant File Content:

`/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/COOKBOOK_NAME/recipes/RECIPE_NAME.rb`:

```
 1:  # Comments
 2:
 3:  default['sssd']['simple']['allow_groups'] = 'GROUP_NAME' if node.chef_environment == 'production'
 4>> default['sssd']['simple']['allow_groups'] = 'GROUP_NAME' unless node.chef_environment == 'production'
 5:
 6:  if node.chef_environment == 'production'
 7:    sudo 'sudoers_file' do
 8:      group '%GROUP_NAME'
 9:    end
10:  else
11:    sudo 'sudoers_file' do
12:      group '%GROUP_NAME'
13:    end
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify which chef version are you using since there is [a deprecation of methods of setting\reading the node attribute](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_attributes.html).

try to use `node.default`, rather then `default`.

setting a node attribute in a recipe is usually done because of the value is only known at chef-client convergance phase. if that is not the case, consider moving the node attribute to an attribute file.

note that i am using this cookbook and i have no issue with it.